# Set a menu item to display during certain times

Tags: cron

I have a "utility navigation" on the top of my website that currently has two links - one to our blog and the other to the weekly newsletter. We also do a radio show everyday at 5pm, as well as a rerun on Saturday at 7am and 7pm. During this time, I would like a third menu item to appear with a link to the podcast to listen live.

Anyone have a clue on how to do this, without installing a plugin? I figured I would be able to edit the function but I have no idea how to program timers.. :(

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi @paula-shuler, can you provide the code for the button for the third menu item?  Or is it a button or will it be another menu item or a sub-menu item?  Is it linking to a page or an off site link?  Need to know a bit more info

Comment: It depends very much on how your theme is currently creating the navigation. It could be a WP Menu, it could be hard-coded, we don't know without you providing the relevant code which is probably somewhere in your `header.php` file. If you can share that code we can help you with a time conditional, without having to add a plugin.

Comment: @rudtek thanks for your comments! The third menu item will just be a text link to the podcast link, where the radio show will be broadcasted live, nothing special at all! I added a function to the function.php where I added the menu item (just displays the date for now). I was hoping this is where I could add the time condition to change the link.

Comment: @WebElaine it is definitely a WP Menu

Comment: Is there a way to do a php date/time condition for the day of the week and time? :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to edit theme files, you'll first want to determine whether you're using a custom-built theme or something that was downloaded from somewhere. If it was downloaded from somewhere, you'll need to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) (basically, you just create a new `style.css` file which only needs to contain comments at the top, which let WordPress recognize it as a theme you can activate - and then you copy whichever file you're editing, probably `header.php`, into your theme and make edits there). This way whenever your main theme is updated your child theme will still apply your changes.

Then, in header.php, you'll change code that should look something like this (it may be longer but will contain `wp_nav_menu`):

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'header'));
```

to a conditional:

```
$weekdayShowStart = '17';
$weekdayShowEnd = '18';
$satFirstShowStart = '07';
$satFirstShowEnd = '08';
$satSecondShowStart = '19';
$satSecondShowEnd = '20';
$dayAndTime = current_time("N G");
$timestamp = explode(' ', $dayAndTime);
$day = $timestamp[0];
$hour = $timestamp[1];
if(
    ($day < 6 && $hour >= $weekdayShowStart && $hour < $weekdayShowEnd) ||
    ($day == 6 && $hour >= $satFirstShowStart && $hour < $satFirstShowEnd) ||
    ($day == 7 && $hour >= $satSecondShowStart && $hour < $satSecondShowEnd)
) {
    // paste your old code here, but change 'menu' value to 'radio_show_live_menu'
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'radio_show_live_menu'));
} else {
    // paste your old code here, with no changes
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'header'));
}
```

Explanation:

Using WordPress's `current_time("N G")` gives you N, which is a day of the week, with Monday=1 through Sunday=7, as well as G, which is the hour of the day, with midnight=00 through 11 PM=23.

If your show is more than one hour you'll want to edit the show start and end values above.

You'll need to make sure WordPress is set to use your local time zone to ensure that things happen at the time you expect. You can do that in Settings > General.

Finally, this new code looks for 2 separate menus. If your show is on, it will pull from a *new* menu which you need to create. If your show isn't on, it will pull from the old/existing menu.

To create the new menu: in your (child) theme's `functions.php` file, add

function radio_show_live_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('radio_show_live_menu', __('Radio Live Menu'));
}
add_action('init', 'radio_show_live_menu');

You can then copy the existing menu into the new one and add the extra link.

Comment: You are AMAZING!!! I never thought it would be THIS simple.. I guess I was just overthinking it too much. Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the show, but I'd put the whole function in the functions.php.  No need to edit the header.php:
You'll want to make sure you're in the right timezone too and IMHO Stringtotime is a bit easier to understand.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_nav_menu_profile_link');
function my_nav_menu_profile_link($menu) {
    $livesite = '#';  //link to add to show
    $linkdescription = 'Live broadcast';  //what the link will say on frontend
    $currdate = date('now'); //may need to set your timezone if it is different than server time.

    //saturday morning show
    if ($currdate >= strtotime ('Saturday 7am') && $currdate <= strtotime ('saturday 8am') ) {
         $livelink = '<li><a href="'.$livesite.'" >'.$linkdescription.'</a></li>';
         $menu = $menu . $livelink;
      return $menu;

    //Saturday evening show
        } elseif ($currdate >= strtotime ('Saturday 7pm') && $currdate <= strtotime ('saturday 8pm')) {
         $livelink = '<li><a href="'.$livesite.'" >'.$linkdescription.'</a></li>';
         $menu = $menu . $livelink;
      return $menu;

    //evening shows everyday
    } elseif  ($currdate >= strtotime ('5pm') && $currdate <= strtotime ('6pm')) {
         $livelink = '<li><a href="'.$livesite.'" >'.$linkdescription.'</a></li>';
         $menu = $menu . $livelink;
      return $menu;

    //other times no live show         
    } else {
    return $menu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Love the alternative, though my personal preference is to edit header.php because then it's easier to track down what's making the change later. Too many filters makes it confusing to hunt down later. :) But just a personal preference - this is easier to read.